# Minify CSS files via git hook

Tags: git, githooks

My ideal situation is to automatically minify CSS files and add them to the git commit. I'm not sure if #4 below can be done, but I would like the following flow to be performed:

1. Modify CSS file
2. Add to staging area
3. Commit
4. **Run script that updates the minified files and adds them to the commit**
5. Commit completes

If there is another way, I'd be interested in that as well.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as git hooks are not meant to modify a commit. Further, I believe that the process of minification should be part of deployment, and minified files should never be added to the repository.

Comment: +1 for not adding minified files to repository.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - care to explain the reasoning behind not having the files in git? My reasoning for having them is to make sure they get minified when they are changed, so we don't have to worry about it in the deploy process. Which makes the deploy process simpler, no need to worry about having the tools in that environment, when you are deploying.

Comment: @emostar: The rule of thumb is not to track things which can be generated from what is tracked. Obviously it's not necessary, and can increase repo size, but even if that's not a factor, it provides a potential way for things to get out of sync. What if the hook doesn't run properly one time, and you don't notice? What if one dev uses it and another doesn't? And are you prepared to deal with merge conflicts in the minified files too? Besides, you're making your deploy process (maybe) simpler at the expense of your development process.

Comment: @emostar I agree with Jefromi and want to clarify that in order for such a git hook to work, _every_ developer will have to make sure to manually add the git hook to every machine they ever work on. How is that simpler than minifying in deployment? Further, does minifying your CSS really take that long that you can't afford to do it on every deploy even if the files haven't changed? You could always add logic to your deploy script to compare timestamps if you feel necessary. Finally, you may be saving time in deployment, but every single commit will require minifying, slowing your commit time.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall, @Jefromi: I see your logic and think I will modify the deploy script. The main reason I wanted to do it in the git hook was because I can detect which files need to be minified and only minify the ones that need it. Also, the development environment will have the minify tools while the deploy environment probably doesn't (dev is in EC2, deploy is done locally).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether you should is another matter, but you can.

in .git/hooks/, write a script in your language of choice (make sure it's executable) named pre-commit
in that script, run your minifier command, and do 'git add '

here's an example of someone who minifies javascript this way:
https://gist.github.com/786460

a test hook I wrote:

```
#/bin/sh

tr "aeiou" "AEIOU" < test1.css > test1_diff.css
git add test1_diff.css
```

after running the commit, test1_diff.css was in the working directory, and in git, tracked.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a "pre-commit hook" which gets called before/as your actual commit is made. Google it -- it basically just involved putting a `pre-commit` script file in your `.git` folder.

Comment: Do you think I didn't read the manpage, search Google, and search SO beforehand? I am asking for what kind of pre-commit hook I can use to get what I want done.

Comment: I don't think the downvote or comment is warranted. You did not once use the term `pre-commit hook` in your question so I was giving you exactly the right term that would help you move in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Write a smudge/clean script and mark your css files with the filter attribute. The trick is to do the work on a branch that does not have the attribute and deploy from the one that does. This is easy to set up if you back merge from the deploy branch initially with an ours merge strategy. This ensures that subsequent merges don't propagate the attribute.

That should do what you want.