# Minify Stylesheets and Scripts With Git Hooks

Tags: git

I don't have any experience using hooks in Git, but I'm curious if it's possible to minify stylesheets/scripts using them.

I have a development server, and a live server. I'd like to use a hook to minify the files when I do a pull from the live server, so that they're minified live, but I can continue to work with the unminified versions on the development server.

Comment: Have you checked this out yet?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334671/minify-css-files-via-git-hook

Comment: @Mark The comments seems to suggest hooks can't change the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hooks is just shell scripts. rename post-commit.sample to the post-commit and add command line to this file